# queryByTestId is null after waitFor in unit test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

In my unit test, I want to click an element in my wrapper component that affects the child component. The queryByTestId works before the await waitFor call, but the 2nd queryByTestID returns "null". I'm trying to test what happens in the child component when the language changes.

In my test I have the following:

```
const { queryByTestId, container } = render(
                <TestIntlWrapper>
                    <MyComponent />
                </TestIntlWrapper>
        );
        expect(queryByTestId("test-intl-wrapper")).toBeInTheDocument;
        await waitFor(() => expect(mockedAxios.get).toBeCalledTimes(expectedNumOfAPICalls));
        expect(mockedAxios.get).toBeCalledWith(expectedURL1);
        expect(mockedAxios.get.mock.calls[1][0]).toBe(expectedURL2);
        expect(mockedAxios.get.mock.calls[thirdCall][0]).toBe(expectedURL3);
        expect(queryByTestId("test-intl-wrapper")).toBeInTheDocument; //queryByTestId returns null here
```

TestIntlWrapper.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IntlProvider } from "react-intl";

interface TestIntlWrapperProps {
    children: JSX.Element
}

export default function TestIntlWrapper({children}: TestIntlWrapperProps) {
    const languages = ["en", "es", "fr"]
    const [currentLanguage, setCurrentLanguage] = useState(languages[0]);
    const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);
    const setClick = () => {
        setClickCount(clickCount + 1)
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentLanguage(languages[clickCount % languages.length]);
    },[clickCount] )
    
    return (
        <div data-testid="test-intl-wrapper" onClick={setClick}>
            <IntlProvider locale={currentLanguage}>
                {children}
            </IntlProvider>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example using https://stackblitz.com/?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the application was throwing an uncaught error in the waitFor which is why it was running an empty div and the data-testid was disappearing.